# Transaction values not showing up

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics. I am currently tracking page view and events on my app (Roku), and it works fine. I recently started working on tracking e-commerce data via the transaction event. It partially works.

I see the transactions and revenues coming through, but I am missing: Quantity, Product, Product Sku, and Product Category.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ecomm) is the guide I am using to build the url

Here are a couple sample urls:

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=000000000&t=transaction&ti=1963156480&in=Roti%20%7C%20UVBuy%20%7C%20UV&tr=1.99&ip=1.99&iq=1&ic=566847&iv=Buy

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=000000000&t=transaction&ti=1366274816&in=Buffet%20Froid%20%7C%20UVBuy%20%7C%20UV&tr=1.99&ip=1.99&iq=1&ic=566835&iv=Buy

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=000000000&t=transaction&ti=1963156480&in=Roti&tr=1.99&ip=1.99&iq=1&ic=566847&iv=Buy

Outside of changing my tid, and cid everything else is verbatim. As you can see item name(in), quantity(iq), category(iv) and sku(ic) have values in all three examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the transaction and the item.

[Article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#ecom)

And here are urls:

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=00000000000&ti=1562682880&t=transaction&tr=0.99&ta=Roku&ts=0&tt=0&cu=USD

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=0000000000&ti=1562682880&t=item&in=Movie&ip=0.99&iq=1&ic=584789&iv=Buy&cu=USD

Make sure you have the same transaction id for both the transaction and the item. Also the type (t) for transaction is transaction and the type for the items is item.